# Have epydoc automatically run doctests

Tags: python, doctest, epydoc

I have a nightly epydoc job to generate documentation, but I would also like it to run my docstring tests.  Does anyone know a way of having it automatically run docstring tests on every file it creates documentation for?

I tried inserting this code into the main block of epydoc

```
import doctest
doctest.testmod()
```

but to no avail.  It looks for doctests in that block, and naturally there aren't any.  I get this output:

```
1 items had no tests:
    __main__
0 tests in 1 items.
0 passed and 0 failed.
Test passed.
```